# how to use python urllib2 with delay on response?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, bots

I want to load an internet page,wait to the info to be fully loaded (takes about 10 sec) and then download the site's source.

something like`urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/")` but with wait.
Is there  a easy way to do that and wait between the site opening and the data download? how?

thanks,
Itzik Kidana

#### sorry for beeing noob...

Comment: use `sleep(10)` for wait 10 sec

Answer (score 1):

Using `time.sleep(10)` may work but it's not optimal. I assume you want the javascript of the page to load and then get the page source. For this you can use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It opens a browser and perform all kinds of shenanigans on a web page, check out the documentation. If it's for scraping purposes I'd have a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)